# Google Sheets - How to COUNTIF multiple values in each one cell of column

Tags: google-sheets

Each cell has multiple values that separated by comma and I want to count a value.

Let say I want to count **Mapping Your Future**. How to do that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

delete everything you got and use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, questionnaire!G:G), ","))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''"))
```